# 16.04 and Brother DCP-7040 scanner

Tags: 16.04, scanner, brother

Has anyone been able to get a dcp-7040 scanner working properly? On 14.04 I've gotten it to work by using the Brother install tool

1. adding

   ```
   # Brother scanners
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01ea", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
   ```

   to the end of `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` and editing `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`
2. by putting

   ```
   # 'libusb' device nodes
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0666"
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
   ```

   into that folder and now everything works.

I can't for the life of me get the scanner to work in 16.04 tho. I can print, just not scan. It doesn't even show the scanner as available in simple scan.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation as DualSportDad. Here is the output from dpkg as requested by Neni.

```
michel@hp:$ sudo dpkg -l | grep Brother

ii  brdcp7040lpr:i386         2.0.2-1    i386   Brother DCP-7040 LPR driver
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1   1.0.0-1    all    Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey               0.2.4-1    amd64  Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan3                   0.2.13-1   amd64  Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7040:i386   2.0.2-1    i386   Brother DCP7040 CUPS wrapper driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser    3-3build1  amd64  printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch     1.4-1      amd64  printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Ubuntu 16.04 was a clean install and I specified a USB connection when installing the drivers. The printer does not even have a ethernet connection.

I added the udev rule manually, when the changes along the lines of those mentionned by DualSportDad did not work although they did do the trick in 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the dcp-135c and solved it by following instructions from this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321613&page=3

The problem for me was that the files for sane where installed in the wrong directory. I had to copy all files from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib and all files from /usr/lib64/sane to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane.

Some people had to copy the files from /usr/lib64/sane to /usr/lib/sane instead.

So after you edit your udev rules, try this:

1. Copy all files from */usr/lib64* to */usr/lib*

   `sudo cp /usr/lib64/* /usr/lib`
2. Copy all files from */usr/lib64/sane* to */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane*

   `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

Answer (score 0):

The DCP-7040 scanner can be successfully installed in ubuntu 17.10 following the suggestion by samy.

1. Get latest Driver Install Tool from  the Brother Support and Download page at http://support.brother.com/. Currently it is dated 12/25/2017.
2. Execute the installer (currently named linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1) as root.
3. Create a symbolic link in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/ named libsane-brother3.so.1 pointing to /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1.0.7 which is where the Brother library was installed.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1.0.7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1
   ```

I also fiddled with the sane configuration, but I don't think that was necessary. Details here [Installing the DCP-7040 Scanner in Ubuntu 17.10](https://sigmdel.ca/michel/program/misc/brother_dcp7040_scanner_on_ubuntu_1710_en.html).

Perhaps this would work in 16.04.